# Label control not rendering properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have (what should be) a very simple Windows Forms application.  There is a "Main" form that is a bunch of data input with a Submit button.  When the user presses Submit, I want to display a second form that is a very basic form with only a label on it saying something like, "Please wait...".  I created the second form, and in the Submit button's Click() I do this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
f2.Hide();
```

Form2's ctor:

```
public Form2()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Text = "Form2 that is useless";
}
```

What I see is the Form2, but where the label should be, I only see the outline of it as a white reactangle with no text.  Text foreground and background colors check out (black foreground on "Control" colored background.

I am pulling my hair out here trying to determine why a simple form added with no property changes will not display controls properly.  I added a button control and a picture box control and got the same results.  the control's outline shows up, but the contents do not.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
Shown += new EventHandler(Form2_Shown);
```

to Form2's ctor. And:

```
void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Update();
}
```

In its class.

EDIT:
This doesn't work. Probably because the `Sleep` is executed before the `Shown` event handler. The solution is to add a:

```
f2.Update();
```

before the `Sleep`, *instead* of the previous solution.

This time I tried it. It works.

Comment: I made the Form2 class like this, but the end result remains the same: public partial class Form2 : Form
 {
  public Form2()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Text = "Form2 that is useless";
   Shown += new EventHandler(Form2_Shown);
  }

  void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   this.Update();
  }

Comment: @JoeBaltimore _Instead_ of my answer, just add: `f2.Update();` right before the `Sleep`. (I tried it. It works.)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't giving Form2 a chance to render itself.

Try using a Timer on your second form (instead of that `Sleep()` method you have) that will close it after your 3,000 milliseconds.  Start it in the Shown event.  Close the form in the Tick event.

```
public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Text = "Form2 that is useless";
  timer1.Interval = 3000;
}

private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am certainly doing something wrong, but this solution did not produce the desired results.

Comment: @JoeBaltimore I had a timer placed on Form2, wired the Shown and Tick events, and the form closed 3 seconds after showing it.  What results did you get?